# How to filter a cross table with PHP and MySQL and AND, OR and NOT Operator

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of customers:

```
customers
id name
1  test
2  test2
```

And a table of groups:

```
groups
id name
1  g1
2  g2
3  g3
4  g4
```

And a cross table:

```
rs_customers_groups
customerid groupid
1          1
1          3
2          1
2          4
```

That's all i currently have for testing.

What I want to do is to filter my cross table using a HTML-Formular that looks like that where I can say AND, OR and NOT:

[image: form]

My PHP looks like that and creates the following query:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST["build"])){
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM rs_customers_groups WHERE 1 AND ';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
             if($key != 'build'){
                  echo $key." ".$value."<br />";
                  if($value == 0){
                      $operator = "OR";
                      //$query.='('.$operator.' gruppe = '.$key.')';
                  }else if($value == 1){
                        $operator == "OR";
                  } else if($value == 2){
                        $operator == "NOT";
                  }
            }
        }
         echo $query.'<br />';
     }
?>
```

SELECT * FROM rs_customers_group WHERE 1 AND groupid = 1 AND groupid = 2

Alright, that's what I have done already. 
What I want to do is creating a filter.

For example:

When my form is like
g1 AND
g2 NOT
g3 AND
g4 NOT

I want all customers that are in group 1 AND 3 but NOT in group 2 AND 4. The result should be customer 1.

When my form is like this:
g1 AND
g2 NOT
g3 NOT
g4 NOT

I want all customers that are in group 1 but NOT in 2,3 and 4

Would there be AND and NOT enought and I do not need the OR option?

thanks!

Comment: AND/OR/NOT are not the same _category_: you need to separate AND/OR from NOT. w/out NOT: `SELECT * FROM rs_customers_group WHERE 1 AND (groupid = 1 $operator groupid = 2)` With this query, you can also remove `WHERE 1 AND `

Comment: This is a typical pantry problem. Show me recipes with ingredients a, b, and c but not x, y, and z

Comment: @fusion3k I don't get it. Trying to build this query gives me the following query: `SELECT * FROM rs_kunden_gruppen WHERE 1 AND (gruppe = 1 AND gruppe = 3)` and the result is empty again. Do you have a more specifiy example for me?

Comment: Florian, do **you** have a more specific example for us? Please edit question adding: 1) table sample (header and some rows); 2) desired result with AND condition; 3) desired result with OR condition; 4) desired result with NOT condition (if any). Please make sure that desired results are coherent with table sample. We have to know what is your goal to help you. :)

Comment: @fusion3k I have edited my post. Is it more understandable now? :)

Comment: There is a logical issue in your form/query: if I select `g1=AND/g2=OR/g3=OR` the query is `(g1 AND g2) OR g3)` or `g1 AND (g2 OR g3)` . With 4 options possible combinations are a lot. Sure you don't intend a **global** 'AND/OR ' and single 'EQUAL/NOT' ?